# Convert json structure to a usable javascript data set

Tags: javascript, json

I have a lil bit problem about json format, I have a json like this

```
{
"h": [
        "username",
        "class",
        "height"
    ],
"d": [
        [
            "aji",
            "a",
            9.9
        ],
        [   
            "mail",
            "a",
            2.2
        ],
        [   
            "dono",
            "b",
            2.4
        ],
        [   
            "parti",
            "c",
            1.2
        ]
    ]
}
```

and what I want is I want convert my json to be like this with javascript? Do I have to convert my json to array first or just do some looping with my array?

```
[
{
    "username":"aji",
    "class":"a",
    "height": 9.9
},
{
    "username":"mail",
    "class":"a",
    "height":2.2
},
{
    "username":"dono",
    "class":"b",
    "height":2.4
},
{
    "username":"parti",
    "class":"c",
    "height":1.2
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/539/)

```js
var newData = [];
for (prop in data.d) {
  newData.push({
    [data.h[0]]: data.d[prop][0],
    [data.h[1]]: data.d[prop][1],
    [data.h[2]]: data.d[prop][2]
  })
}

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Ohh it works!, is there some way where we dont need to declare the props like username, class, height manually?

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution with two iterations.

```js
var data = { "h": ["username", "class", "height"], "d": [["aji", "a", 9.9], ["mail", "a", 2.2], ["dono", "b", 2.4], ["parti", "c", 1.2]] },
    array = data.d.map(function (a) {
        var o = {};
        a.forEach(function (b, i) {
            o[data.h[i]] = b;
        });
        return o;
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```